# Svelte / D3 Function to get Point on a Path

Tags: svg, d3.js, svelte

I'd like to create a function that gets the coordinates of the nth point along an SVG path, while using Svelte and D3.

[image]

Note, the blue dot is not part of the code and there just for illustration.

I've tried this...

```
    // the path generator
    const pathLine = line()
        .x(d => xScale(d.age))
        .y(d => yScale(d.temp))
        .curve(curveBasis);
    
    function pointFromPath(position){
        pos = pathLine(data).getPointAtLength(position);
        return pos
    }

    $: console.log(pointFromPath(2))
```

...

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    {#if (show)}
        <path transition:draw={{duration: 2000}}
                    d={pathLine(data)} />
    {/if}
</svg>
```

But it doesn't work and I'm not sure what to try next.  My redproducable code is here

https://svelte.dev/repl/189b1ff0485f4697b3061dd29daf1d3a?version=3.32.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pathLine(data) is returning a string representing the "d" and not the DOM-element itself.

See a working example here:

https://svelte.dev/repl/76d1d7d0a38b4f6c9f02f9ffb0200ea5?version=3.32.3