# Using svelte's draw transition does not work if the `d`-attribute of a svg-path is returned by a function

Tags: javascript, svg, svelte

So I have a very simple svelte-component like this:

```
<script>
    import {draw} from "svelte/transition"
    function path(){
        return `M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"`
    }
    let checked = false
</script>
    
<svg>
    {#if checked}
       <path transition:draw={{duration: 2000}} d={path()} fill="none" stroke="black"/>
    {/if}
</svg>
<input type="checkbox" bind:checked>
```

I want to animate the appearance of the black square. It works with the code like this. However if I omit the checkbox and directly render the svg, it does not work. I think this is a similar problem as in this question: [Svelte / D3 Function to get Point on a Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301315/svelte-d3-function-to-get-point-on-a-path)

I just did not really understand why and would be grateful for any explanation on how I could use the `draw` directive "top-level" when the svg renders initially.

Comment: You link shows only a generic svelte example. Please share you current script to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo. At the end of the string you have a stray  **"**: ` return `M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"`

Comment: sorry, just a typo...:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions only run when the element is inserted, not when the element exists from the beginning.

So if you just want to draw once, you could add a flag like `let show = false`, set that to `true` in [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount) and wrap the SVG in an `{#if show}`.